# OpenSSL SHA256 generates different sum for the same file

Tags: c++

I have never worked with SHA256 before. Recently, I've been trying to implement a SHA256 checksum in order to see if a library has been tampered with.

The funny thing is that OpenSSL SHA256 generates a different sum for the exact same library depending on its location. If it's located in another folder, the sum is different.

Is there anything I could do to get the same sum no matter where the file is located? I provided the code snippets and the sums I get.

```
unsigned char* getsum( char* filename ) {
    std::ifstream pFile( filename, std::ios::binary );
    SHA256_CTX sContext;
    char pBuffer[ 1024*16 ];
    unsigned char pSum[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    SHA256_Init( &sContext );
    while( pFile.good() ) {
        pFile.read( pBuffer, sizeof(pBuffer) );
        SHA256_Update( &sContext, pBuffer, pFile.gcount() );
    }
    SHA256_Final( pSum, &sContext );
    return pSum;
}

...

char* cl_sum = new char[256];
sprintf( cl_sum, "%02x", getsum("library.dll") );
MessageBoxA( NULL, cl_sum , NULL, NULL );
delete[] cl_sum;
exit( -1 );
```

[image]

[image]

I also tried using the SHA256() function instead of the whole SHA256 context, SHA256_Init(), Update & Final thing, but still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has lots of basic mistakes:

```cpp
sprintf( cl_sum, "%02x", getsum("library.dll") );
```

Format string says "print me int value", `getsum` returns `char *`! This is wrong and if you use compiler warnings it should explain issue.

Return value is wrong too:

```cpp
unsigned char* getsum( char* filename ) {
    ...
    unsigned char pSum[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    ...
    return pSum;
}
```

You are returning a pointer to local object which lifetime ends when function returns.

Here is my tweak to your code

```cpp
using Sha256Hash = std::array<unsigned char, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH>;

Sha256Hash calcSha256Hash(std::istream& in)
{
    SHA256_CTX sContext;
    SHA256_Init(&sContext);

    std::array<char, 1024> data;
    while (in.good()) {
        in.read(data.data(), data.size());
        SHA256_Update(&sContext, data.data(), in.gcount());
    }
    Sha256Hash hash;
    SHA256_Final(hash.data(), &sContext);
    return hash;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y3nY13jao

Side note: I'm surprised that [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) sets failure bit when end of file is reached and some data has bee read. This is a inconsistent with behavior of streaming operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to local variable `pSum`, that is undefined behaviour(UB).

An explanation for differen outputs might be that since the array is located on stack, calls to future functions like `sprintf` or `MessageBoxA` likely overwrite the array with their own variables. But anything can happen after UB.

Use and return `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead.

Also do not use `new`, instead `std::array` or another `std::vector` is much safer.

Lastly, I would strongly advise to turn on compiler warnings for your compiler, it should warn about the above issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely try that, but the thing is if the library (and the whole application for that matter) is in the same folder the sum is the same, it never changes, but if I move it someplace else it does change

Comment: @stuck Okay, that is possible but it is futile to argue about UB, fix the code first and check if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's output depends on what value `getsum` returns. The value `getsum` returns is an address on the stack. So your code's output depends on where the stack is located.

Somewhere in your code, you should save the result of the SHA256 operation in a buffer of some kind and you should output the *contents* of that buffer. Your code does neither of those two things.

If you think you save the output of the SHA256 operation in some kind of buffer, where do you think that buffer is allocated. The only buffer you use is `pBuffer`, and that's allocated on the stack in `getsum` and so doesn't exist when `getsum` returns.

If you think you actually look in the buffer somewhere, where do you think that code is? Your `sprintf` call never looks *in* the buffer, it just outputs a pointer in hex.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- your function is returning a pointer to a local variable. When your function exits, the variable is destroyed, leaving the returned pointer dangling.
- you are printing the *value* of the returned pointer itself (ie, the memory address it holds), not the SHA data that it points at. That is why you are seeing the same value being displayed in the message box. You are seeing the memory address of the local variable, and multiple invocations of your function may reuse the same memory.
- your reading loop is not  making sure that `read()` is successful before calling `SHA256_Update()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
using Sha256Digest = std::array<unsigned char, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH>;

Sha256Digest getsum( const char* filename ) {
    std::ifstream file( filename, std::ios::binary );
    SHA256_CTX sContext;
    char buffer[ 1024*16 ];   
    Sha256Digest sum;

    SHA256_Init( &sContext );
    while( file.read( buffer, sizeof(buffer) ) ) {
        SHA256_Update( &sContext, buffer, pFile.gcount() );
    }
    SHA256_Final( sum.data(), &sContext );

    return sum;
}

...

Sha256Digest sum = getsum("library.dll");

char cl_sum[256] = {}, *ptr = cl_sum;
for (auto ch : sum) {
   ptr += sprintf( ptr, "%02x", ch );
}
MessageBoxA( NULL, cl_sum, NULL, NULL );

/* Alternatively:

std::ostringstream cl_sum;
for (auto ch : sum) {
    cl_sum << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ch;
}
MessageBoxA( NULL, cl_sum.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL );
*/
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Indeed this helped, I managed to figure out that it returns the address, funnily enough if I format it as a string (%s) everything is fine, but when I'm trying to format it as hex (%02x) it gives the memory address instead, I made a pretty dumb workaround converting it char by char and then returning the final array

Comment: "*if I format it as a string (%s) everything is fine*" - because that prints the data which the pointer is pointing at, not prints the value of the pointer itself. But in the code you provided, this is still undefined behavior, as the returned pointer is invalid, and the final hash is not textual data to begin with. "*but when I'm trying to format it as hex (%02x) it gives the memory address instead*" - because you are printing the value of the pointer itself, not printing the data it points at.